# weird behavior of boost function

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

My following code runs into error if I comment out the first line in the constructor. The return error is:

```
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<std::overflow_error> >: Error in function boost::math::cyl_bessel_k<double>(double,double): numeric overflow
Abort trap: 6
```

However, it is weird that if I output something (e.g., uncomment the first line) in the constructor, then my program works fine.

```
GP::GP(const Training_set& _sample, Eigen::VectorXd& param, 
                const std::string& which_kernel) : sample(_sample)
{
//      std::cout << "WORKS" << std::endl;
        if (which_kernel == "Matern") {
                std::cout << "Matern kernel is used!" << std::endl;
                Kernel_Matern matern(param, param.size());
                kernel = &matern;
        } else if (which_kernel == "Square_Exponential") {
                std::cout << "Square Exponential kernel is used!" << std::endl;
                Kernel_SE se(param, param.size());
                kernel = &se;
        } else {
                std::cout << "Cannot identify the kernel" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
        }   
        input_dim = sample.dim;
        input_size = sample.size;
        L_chol.resize(sample.size, sample.size);
        Eigen::MatrixXd cov_matrix = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(sample.size, sample.size);
        get_cov_matrix(sample.X, input_size, sample.X, input_size, cov_matrix);
        get_chol(cov_matrix);
}
```

Comment: You assign address of temporary variable that goes out of scope to `kernel` .

Comment: `kernel` is a dangling pointer that outlives the data it points at.

Comment: @VTT You are right!!! What would be a good way to correct this? "kernel" is a private class in class GP. I want to initialize "kernel" to "Matern" or "Square_Exponential" depending on the users' choice.

Comment: @Frank Thanks, that's error. But how to properly use polymorphism in this case?

Comment: `kernel = std::make_unique<MatrixType>(param, param.size());`

Comment: What is the scope of `kernel`, class level?  Is it used outside of the constructor?  If not, why isn't a local constructor variable?  If so, how in the world did your program not crash?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont kernel is a private member of the class and is supposed to be used outside the constructor as well. The problem is that the subclass matern is local to the constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing an address of a temporary that goes out of scope.  Using `*kernel` after what it points to goes out of scope is undefined behavior.

`kernel` should be of type `std::unique_ptr<X>` instead of type `X*`.

Replace assignment with:

```
 kernel = std::make_unique<Kernel_Matern>(param, param.size());
```

or:

```
 kernel = std::make_unique<Kernel_SE>(param, param.size());
```

at the two lines in question.

If you have code where you pass `kernel` to a function, instead pass `kernel.get()`.

Note that is blocks copying instances of `GP` but not moving them, as unique ptr is move-only.  If you have a type that stores both values and pointers into its own values, copying it is probably a bug anyhow.